# How I can to skip some area of text, when reading file?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-parsing

I reading a `.txt` file and want to skip a listing of code in this text, when putting result in `StringBuilder`.

The example of text:

> The following Bicycle class is one possible implementation of a
>   bicycle:
>
> /* The example of Bicycle class class Bicycle {
>
> int cadence = 0;
>
> int speed = 0; } */

So that's what I could come to:

```
public class Main {

public static BufferedReader in;
public static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "input_text.txt";

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String inputText;

    try {
        while ((inputText = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputText.startsWith("/*")) {

// The problem is there:

                while (!inputText.endsWith("*/")) {
                    int lengthLine = inputText.length();
                    in.skip((long)lengthLine);
                }
            }
                stringBuilder.append(inputText);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got the infinity `while` loop and can't jump to next line.

Comment: You never reset the value of `inputText` in your while loop

Comment: `inputText`  never changes inside  the `while (!inputText.endsWith("*/"))` loop.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, BufferedReader took a line with `/*`, and I can't understand how to jump to the next line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset the value of `inputText` in your `while` loop, so it will never not end with `*/` resulting in an infinite loop. Also you don't need to use the `skip()` method as simply reading the lines until you encounter a `*/` will work. Try changing your loop to:

```
 while (!inputText.endsWith("*/")) {       
        String temp = in.readLine();
        if(temp == null) {break;}
        inputText = temp;                                                           
 }
```

*Output:* (With printing the `StringBuilder`)

```
The following Bicycle class is one possible implementation of a bicycle:
```

Comment: I'm catching `NullPointException` in this `while` loop

Comment: @SpikeJohnson At which line?

Comment: while (!inputText.endsWith("*/")) {